# Why does orbot's source code contain binary files for iptables?

Tags: source-code, orbot

According to [a ticket](https://dev.guardianproject.info/issues/1735) in your bug tracker, the source code for [Orbot](https://www.torproject.org/docs/android.html.en) contains binary files for iptables.

To me, this sounds like Orbot is built off of some closed-source code. How then could this portion be scrutinized? Should we be worried about this?

Comment: What ticket? What bug tracker? What binary files?

Comment: Perhaps [ticket 4444](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/4444): “Iptables-binary bundled with Orbot segfaults on Android 2.3.5”?

Comment: iptables is not closed source. http://www.netfilter.org/licensing.html

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the binaries got removed from the current development tree with [git commit 9d6f3c8](https://gitweb.torproject.org/orbot.git/commit/9d6f3c836b5c81c2565ff5744955129fc370a5ed) in August 2013 as they were apperently "unneeded old".

Comment: link to (still open) ticket: https://dev.guardianproject.info/issues/1735

Comment: I know iptables is open source, but you can't verify that these files were compiled from the original source because the are already compiled.

Comment: Seems like the binaries were not removed. Found iptables in orbot's current version (12.0.5) source. page for that file's history shows it was added back in AFTER the commit you linked to: https://gitweb.torproject.org/orbot.git/history/HEAD:/res/raw/iptables Fdroid is hosting an old version of orbot for this very reason. They only host fully open source code.

Comment: @cory, clarified my statement - it was only about the current git tree.